# Currency Math in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please help me out with a JavaScript/jQuery solution for this arithmetic problem:

I need to subtract one number from the other.

The problem is that the numbers have a dollar sign (because its money), therefore jQuery is treating them as strings instead of numbers.

I have created two variables - `toalAssets` and `totalLiabilites`.  I would like to subtract the latter from the former and place the result into another variable called `netWorth`.

Perhaps i need to use `parseFloat()`?

But I'm not sure how - This is all a little over my head!

Comment: @Mark: he's only asked 5 questions and has 36 rep, so is obviously new to the site.

Comment: @Jared: You can go back to your old questions (click your username at the top) and accept answers on them if appropriate. More people will be likely to answer future questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var totalLiabilites = '$52.34';
var toalAssets      = '$85.12';
var pattern         = /[^0-9.-]+/g;

var result = parseFloat(toalAssets.replace(pattern, '')) -
             parseFloat(totalLiabilites.replace(pattern, ''));

// result: 32.78
```

**Note:** In JavaScript it is recommended<sup>1</sup> to handle money as an integer representing the number of cents (8512 instead of 85.12). This is to avoid problems with floating-point arithmetic. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` returns false in JavaScript, but fortunately integer arithmetic in floating point is exact, so decimal representation errors can be avoided by scaling.

You may want to check the following post for further reading on this topic: [Is JavaScript’s math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

You can always apply the currency-sign formatting when the values are rendered to the browser.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Douglas Crockford: [JavaScript: The Good Parts: Appendix A - Awful Parts (page 105)](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA105&dq=douglas+crockford+javascript+good+parts+dollar+values+can+be+converted&rview=1&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).</sub>

Comment: Updated your pattern to allow negatives.

Comment: Caveat Emptor: IF you can avoid fractional cents. In certain situations you cannot: ie aggregate tax calculation, non USD currency, etc.

Answer (score 6):

`parseFloat()` won't work because your string begins with a non-number, the dollar sign.

You can simply do a replace to remove the dollar sign, along with a parseFloat to get the value:

```
totalAssets = parseFloat(totalAssets.replace('$', ''));
totalLiabilities = parseFloat(totalLiabilities.replace('$', ''));

var difference = '$' + (totalAssets - totalLiabilities);
```

This code replaces your original strings with floats.  You could load them into new variables as well.  Likewise, difference does not have to have the '$' prepended.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "$20";
var b = "$34";
var c = parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) - parseFloat(b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
alert(c);
```

Comment: Daniel - what does this gobbledegook mean please?

/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""