# Encoding BigDecimal with JSON-Lib for Java

Tags: java, json

I am using [JSON-Lib library](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to do JSON encoding. Can't do it with [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (my preferred library when dealing with JSON in Java) or any other libraries because unfortunately my application needs to be Java 1.4 compliant.

My question is:

What's the best way to encode BigDecimal values (values representing money) in that library? Is it just serializing BigDecimal objects as strings with my desired precision?

Comment: If you're just going to display the values, then a string works best.

Comment: No, I am also planning to use the values in calculations and other stuff...

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556338/currency-math-in-javascript

Comment: How much money are you dealing with?  You can hold an awful lot of cents in a Java `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this message](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=json-lib-user&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=200611), JSON-Lib supports `BigDecimal` via the `JSONUtils` class.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for the response. It supports BigDecimal. No problem at all.