# JS: Selecting Numbers Only From Text Field, Plus Simple Calculation?

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the value on the page while when loaded and changing the currency with a simple calculation.

If any one can help me that be great,,

here is my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myscript() {
var input = document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML;
output = '$19,999.9 AUD';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(input,output);
}
</script>
</head>

<span id="span1" class="text field">$9,999.9 USD</span> 
<body OnLoad = "myscript();">
</body>
```

So basically I want to know how to make it take ONLY the numbers from id="span1" text field and do a simple calculation like + 10 and replace USD with AUD without losing the , and .

I have tried to make use of parseInt but didn't get it to work.

Thanks you in advance :)

EDIT:
Please NOTE that the span1 value is dynamic and always changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to just grab the numbers from the string.

```
var regpattern = /[^0-9.-]+/g;
var output= parseFloat(input.replace(regpattern , ''));
output += 10;
```

I would also recommend that the currency type **USD** and **AUD** not be part of the **span1** but be part of **span2** that is shown right after. This way the parsing doesn't need to handle it.

Comment: perfect thanks, would you be able to tell me how to not lose the , and . ? the output only displays the calculation without the ,

Comment: You will lose them. You might have to write functions to put them at the right place. Currency manipulation is kinda tricky. Some countries use , at the 1000th place some don't. Look at @Keith's solution if you need more that simple addition

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner and kinda don't understand much, would it work if i re-edit again the givin value?

Answer (score 0):

This post might be of some help: [Currency Math in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556338/currency-math-in-javascript).

It explains how to use parseFloat combined with string.replace to accomplish parsing currency strings to floats and then doing calculations

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ArXbL/1/ is working for you

Comment: thank you but it doesnt change the USD and doesnt have the calculation part